# I am trying to make a code to conjugate verbs in French, but I cannot change the keys ''je'' to ''j ' ''

Tags: python

I am trying to make my code work like this:

```
Enter a verb in French: chanter

Output 1: je chante
          tu chantes
          il ou elle chante
          nous chantons
          vous chantez
          ils ou elles chantent
```

I succeeded in making the part above, but I cannot succeed in switching `je` to `j'` when the user enters, for instance: `echapper`

```
Enter a verb in French: echapper

Output 2: j'echappe
          tu echappes
          il ou elle echappe
          nous echappons
          vous echappez
          ils ou elles echappent
```

Code:

```
list = {
    "je": 'e',
    "tu": 'es',
    "il ou elle": 'e',
    "nous": 'ons',
    "vous": 'ez',
    "ils ou elles": 'ent'
}

veb = input("")

for key in list:
    if veb.endswith('er'):
        b = veb[:-2]
        print(key, b + list[key])
```

I do not know how to change the key `list['je']` to `list['j'']` to succeed with the Output 2.

Answer (score 0):

If you use double quotes around `j'`, i.e. `"j'"`, it will work. Also, I recommend *not* using the name `list` for your dictionary because 1) it's a dictionary, not a list, and 2) you should avoid using builtin python names for your variables.

Also, looks like that conjugation is treated differently, with "j'" at the beginning and "e" at the end (instead of "er").

```
dictionary = {"je":"j'","tu":'es',"il ou elle":'e',"nous": 
                  'ons',"vous":'ez',"ils ou elles":'ent'}

veb = input("")

for key in dictionary:
    if veb.endswith('er'):
        b = veb[:-2]
        if key == 'je':
            print(key, dictionary[key] + b + 'e')
        else:
            print(key,b + dictionary[key])
```

Answer (score 0):

You should just simply replace the print statement with an if statement:

```
if key == "je" and (veb.startswith("a") or veb.startswith("e") or [etc.]):
    print("j'",b + list[key])
else:
    print(key,b + list[key])
```